# Is there a "whois" for telephone numbers? Can I determine the "last port date"?

Tags: cellular

To combat against phone number porting fraud/hacks, I'd like to verify if a given number

- Has been recently ported (within x days)
- Is queued to be ported
- Has other "whois" attributes that could be a fraud early warning system

That being said, is there any whois I can use to query for a given number, or for the provider of the call-currently-in progress?

... how would I use it to protect against porting attacks?

Comment: Who are you?  An individual or a company that acts as an terminating provider?

Comment: A consumer wants me to send a SMS to their number with some assurance of security. I want to be proactive and tell them if it's risky to do so. (risk = phone # ported)

Comment: This might be useful to you.  You don't sound like a traditional "telecommunications provider" though:  https://www.npac.com/the-npac/access